# Pair wise input redirect - bash

Tags: bash, input, io-redirection

I have a file called input.txt which has the following

```
0 
1
1 
2
2
3
3
4
```

What I would like to do is redirect two lines to a programing like so:

i = 0;

./program < input.txt[i & ++i]

in a loop until it is done with the file.

Anyone know how? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while read line1 && read line2
do
    printf "%s\n" "$line1" "$line2" | ./program
done < input.txt
```

Comment: That does 1 space 2, how would I do 1 \n 2?
Also shouldn't it be     printf "%s\n" "$line1" "$line2" | ./program

Comment: I missed the `$` in `$line2`, yes. But it already does `1 \n 2` not `1 space 2`.